# Store a database file in user-desired Location in Android Device. How can i do it?

Tags: android, android-file

I don't want to store a file in the default "/data/data" location of the device.
I want to store the file on device in any location the user wants.
How can i do it?

I already know to store the file in default location "/data/data" of the device.So please don't give answer for storing in default location.

Comment: I don't thin it is a wise deicsion to store the content in an open directory but still if you want , you can create  .db file in whatever location you want and access it same way.
Though it will be challenging to implement the CRUD operations in that db file seamlessely the way SqliteDbManager or room db does with given APIS.

Comment: @anshul i asked HOW??